# NSMutableDictionary sometimes shows value or key with quotes

Tags: xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I am parsing a data file and adding the key-value read from the file into an NSMutableDictionary.

I have noticed that when I print out the content of the dictionary in the debugger, i.e:
   po myDictionary

some entries have quotes around them and some don't.  Why is this?

For instance I see:

```
{
  "file_path"      = "../dat.txt"
  another_path     = "aa.dat"
  yet_another_path = bb.txt
}
```

I am using the following line to extract the key and value from the file, after parsing the data down to only the essential bytes

```
key_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                   length:total_bytes
                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

val_str is parsed the same way.

Thank you

Comment: What debugger (including version) are you using? When run with GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (the version that comes with XCode 3.2.1) from the command line, all keys & values I see are double quoted.

Comment: Yeah... "bb.txt" would be quoted.  The debugger, btw, has absolutely nothing to do with the format.  The string is entirely generated within the system frameworks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableDictionary is adding quotes to keys and values - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471398/nsmutabledictionary-is-adding-quotes-to-keys-and-values-why)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the output of the `-debugDescription` or `-description` methods for the purposes of data archival.  The format is an implementation detail and subject to change.

I would suggest that you look to [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and related) to solve your archival needs.  It offers an XML format, if you need something akin to human readability.

Comment: Thanks for the replies sofar.

I am using gdb 6.3.50-20050815 on a Mac.

The problem is the quotes actually end up as part of the key.  So, in the posted example:
  po [myDictionary objectForKey:@"file_path"]

this fails because "file_path" has quotes around them in the dictionary.  I don't know how the quotes got there.  That's what I'd like to figure out and get rid of.

Comment: I can't say it enough: **Do not use -debugDescription or -description to generate your keys.**  Those methods are not designed for any purpose other than as a debugging tool

Comment: I don't think I communicated clearly the first time.  So I am not generating my keys from the debugger; I'm reading them from a data file that contains "variable name"-"value" pair.  I am only displaying the debug output as extra information for the purpose of this discussion.

So, the "key_str" here is what I parsed out of a data file.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue.  It appears to be a problem with the JSON parser putting quotes around Keys that contain the underscore character.  So a key of filename is ok but a key with file_name is returned as "file_name".