# How to add quotes to an nsdictionary key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I need to add double quotes to control_text value. However, even though the back slash works for strings, it doesn't work for `NSDictionary` values. Is there a way to handle the following situation?

```
NSDictionary *createText =  @{ @"text": @[ @{ @"type": @"control_text" , @"text": @"text" }]};
```

This is my log:

```
{
    text = (
        {
            text = text;
            type = "control_text";
        }
    );
 }
```

Comment: Post your error message. Backslash escaping quotes works just fine inside `NSString` literals.

Comment: Your syntax is fine.  If you `NSLog` the dictionary then it will show \ before the " to indicate that there is are quotes in the string, but if you log the length of types' value you will get 14 - the length without the \

Comment: It seems that the quotes aren't really part of the content; the -description method simply wraps things in quotes for display that have non-alphanumeric characters in them.

Comment: Why do you want to add double quotes to the keys? They are fine the way they are.

Comment: I'm almost certain that you don't need any more quotes.  Your dump above is how NSLog shows dictionarys and arrays.  If you convert to JSON (which I suspect is the goal) the key values will be quoted, as will "text".

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableDictionary is adding quotes to keys and values - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471398/nsmutabledictionary-is-adding-quotes-to-keys-and-values-why)

Answer (score 0):

A `NSDictionary` keys can include quotes, they just need to be escaped:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"\"n\"" : @"v"};
NSLog(@"d: %@", d);
NSLog(@"n1: %@", d[@"\"n\""]);
NSLog(@"n2: %@", d[@"n"]);
```

Output:

```
d: {
    "\"n\"" = v;
}

n1: v

n2: (null)
```

But it really does not make sense in general to add quotes to the keys.

Don't be confused by `NSLog()`, it uses the `description` method which adds quotes and backslashes for clarity in the manner the Apple developers liked.

Swift:

```
let d1 = ["n" : "v"]      // ["n":"v"]
let d2 = ["\"n\"" : "v"]  // [""n"":"v"]
```

Comment: Actually, NSLog/description effectively *removes* quotes where they're unnecessary.  String values are only quoted if they contain blanks or special characters.  This goes for both keys and values.

Comment: Yes, and while a nice touch that also causes confusion. Personally I would rather have consistency. Note that Swift always shows the quotes and in the case of a quoted key shows double quotes with no backslash. Nice.

Comment: Well, Objective-C's `description` format predates JSON, et al, by a dozen years or so, so it's hard to be real critical of it.  You just gotta know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

What NSLog shows as:

```
{
    text = (
        {
            text = text;
            type = "control_text";
        }
    );
 }
```

when converted to JSON, will appear as:

```
{
    "text":[
        {
            "text":"text",
            "type":"control_text"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Assuming that your goal is to produce JSON, there is no need to add more quotes.